# networkx: error while displaying edge label

Tags: python, pandas, graph, networkx, graph-visualization

> H=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(links,source='source',target='target',edge_attr='value')

this gives me back the list of edges and wegight

> edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(Q, 'value')
> nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(Q, pos=nx.draw(Q),labels=edge_labels ,font_size=8)
> this gives an error

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-99-1783423b22ae> in <module>
----> 1 nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(Q, pos=nx.draw(Q),labels=edge_labels ,font_size=8)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_pylab.py in draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels, label_pos, font_size, font_color, font_family, font_weight, alpha, bbox, ax, rotate, **kwds)
    939     text_items = {}
    940     for (n1, n2), label in labels.items():
--> 941         (x1, y1) = pos[n1]
    942         (x2, y2) = pos[n2]
    943         (x, y) = (x1 * label_pos + x2 * (1.0 - label_pos),

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

i dont understand why this is happening , this does however return a graph, with no node names .
the output graph i want is nodes with their names and corresponding node colour, and have 'values' displayed on the edges.
so far i have been sucessful except for the edge label part

Comment: Pls add your dataframe and more details of your code

Answer (score 0):

This is my standard pattern for labeling Networkx graphs - the sample is a list of FK references in a database schema which is in pandas - output is a list though, so you don't need to have used pandas:

```
weightedGraphPairedLabelList = columnFKDataFrame[["TABLE_NAME", "REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME"]].values.tolist()
thisGraph = nx.DiGraph()
thisGraph.add_edges_from(weightedGraphPairedLabelList)
print(random.choice(weightedGraphPairedLabelList))

Out: ['CreatingEntityAliases', 'CheckTableCEAliasTypes']


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
thisAx = plt.subplot(111)
pos = nx.shell_layout(thisGraph)     #this line is what is placing the nodes - in this case, using spring_layout
nx.draw(thisGraph, pos, node_size=50, edge_color='b', alpha=0.2, with_labels=True)
plt.title("Table Relationships")
plt.show()
```